# How to print odd numbers in increasing order?

Tags: python

I need to print a sequence of odd numbers in increasing order. I can solve it only in decreasing order.

```
num = int(input(print("Type any integer: ")))
count = 1 
while count <= num:
    num -= 1 
    if num % 2 != 0:
        print(num)
```

Comment: With `sorted(..)`.

Comment: But you do not need to sort here, you need to *enumerate* it in the correct way.

Comment: Increment `count` instead of decrementing `num`. And if you only want odd numbers, add 2 each time instead of adding one and checking if they are odd. Btw, what you do isn't called sorting.

Comment: This isn't really about sorting.

Comment: Instead of decrementing `num`, increment `count`

Comment: You really should be using `range` for this.

Comment: What's the expected output in relation to the input?

Comment: simple solution is `list(range(0, num, 2))`

Comment: Please give a sample input-output case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
count = 1
while count <= num:
    print(count)
    count += 2
```

Explanation:
Check if count is less or equal(in case num is odd too) to num. Then, print count before adding to count in increments of 2.

Answer (score 1):

In this case instead of using a `while` loop I'd use a `for`, looping through all your elements:

```
for i in range(num):
    if i%2 != 0:
        print(i)
```

Or you can use `list comprehension`:

```
d = [i for i in range(num) if i%2!= 0]
#Print increasing values
print(d)
#Print decreasing values
print(d[::-1])
```

EDIT: as suggested another possible implementation is:

```
for i in range(1, num, 2):    
    print i
```

The same expression could be also used with list comprehension:

```
d = [i for i in range(1, num, 2)]
```

Comment: Why not: `for i in range(1, num, 2):`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl, yes, that would probably be an even better solution! I'll edit my answer! Thanks!